How to do a matrix optimization by matlab?
I want to solve this optimization problem (which is a simplified demo) by matlab. The optimization variables are A0,B0 which are 4 × 4 symmetric matrices. The constraint is -I≤ A0,B0≤ I. The objective function is max Tr((A0 ⊗ B0)ρ) where ρ is a given matrix.
I used cvx but it reports error because it doesn't support two variables are multiplied. The followings the code which defines the optimization variables ,objective function and constraints but how to write the final solving step?
A0 = sym('A0', [4 4]);
B0 = sym('B0', [4 4]);
rho= rand(16,16);
constraints = {
eye(4) + A0 >= 0,
eye(4) - A0 >= 0, 
eye(4) - B0 >= 0,
eye(4) - B0 >= 0,
};
D00 = kron(A0, B0);

objective = trace(rho * D00);


LaTeX rendering does not work here, please proof read your question and [edit] it to improve legibility. There are other markdown formatting options. What do you mean by that being "some related code"? Is that code you've written which errors or otherwise doesn't produce the result you want? It would be best if you could reformulate it as a [mcve]

You’re solving a numerical problem. Why are you starting with sym? That is for symbolic math, and symbolic math is not numeric math. In a computer, numeric math is cheap, symbolic math is orders of magnitude more expensive. Use symbolic math only if you actually need a symbolic result.

Note also that eye(4) + A0 >= 0 is a matrix, not a single true/false statement. If you want each of the elements of the matrix to satisfy the inequality, use all(eye(4) + A0 >= 0). But in this case, I guess all non-diagonal elements must be 0? You should then use only the diagonal elements as optimization parameters.

Is rho always a diagonal matrix? If it is, you can greatly simplify the expression. I was trying to do this in my head, I might have gone wrong somewhere, but I end up with the sum of all products of the diagonal elements of the two matrices. This is maximal if all those elements are 1. But I might have gone wrong somewhere. Write out your problem on paper, and simplify.

Anyway, here is the docs for the constrained optimization algorithms.

@CrisLuengo The instance I give is just a simple demo (which can get the answer easily) and in the real problem I want to solve, rho is a complicated matrix.

And by eye(4)+A0>=0 I mean it is semidefinite positive instead of all entries are >=0

In that case, you need to write your condition appropriately, see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/determine-whether-matrix-is-positive-definite.html

You should make your example meaningful, for example rho= randn(16)?
